# MS Graph API direct request for users delta @odata.deltaLink

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I am setting up incremental change tracking on users in MS Graph. Based on the documentation for the MS Graph API, the '@odata.deltaLink' token is needed to check changes made after the previous round of delta checking. This token is provided in the final page of user delta API call returns, so what I understand is that I need to scan over all returns until I reach the final change page.

Is there a way to skip straight to the '@odata.deltaLink' token or request it directly? Since I am just starting change tracking I want to start my delta searches from NOW and don't need to track every change up until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the latest delta token by appending `$deltaToken=latest` to the `delta` function

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$deltaToken=latest
```

It supports `$filter` query parameter together with `id` property

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$deltaToken=latest&$filter=id eq 'user1_id' or ... or id eq 'user1_id'
```

Where `id` is the guid, not the service principal name.

Comment: Is there a way to include filters with this? I want to return a specific subset set of fields each time

Comment: @Thoughtful_Giraffe According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#odata-query-parameters), the filter is supported only for id property. You can use **or** and filter max. 50 users.